# Raspberry Pi crashes when building OpenFrameWorks project in Eclipse CDT

Tags: c++, eclipse, raspberry-pi3, openframeworks

I'm working on a Raspberry Pi 3 with OS Raspbian Jessie. I'm using Eclipse CDT (for C/C++) and am trying to learn about OpenFrameWorks:
http://openframeworks.cc/

I installed everything according to the guides and imported everything to Eclipse. I thought it seemed to work out, but when I try to run some test-code I get the error "Unable to launch, binary not found." I look it up and find a potential solution, that I have to build the actual project first.

This is my problem, when I try to build the project Eclipse gets to about 20% and then the entire Raspberry freezes, forcing me to force a restart. How can I continue from here on out? I don't know if I still should try to build the project through Eclipse or if there is another way to actually run some test code for OpenFrameWorks.

I don't know if this is the best place to ask about this, but I'm thankful for all answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse is super slow on Raspberry Pi. 
I recommend using the provided setup scripts to install dependencies. After you [compile OF](http://openframeworks.cc/setup/raspberrypi/raspberry-pi-getting-started/), use make files to compile projects.

In terms of editing code, I recommend using a light weight text editor (geany for example). I've tried CodeBlocks and Qt Creator, which are faster/less resource intensive than eclipse, but still pretty heavy for a system with limited resources.

Another option is to combine your computer the RPi:

1. Use projectGenerator to generate a project for both Raspberry Pi and your computer/IDE
2. Edit/test/iterate on your computer
3. When ready to run on RPi, sync the project using your preferred method(e.g. SSH/SFTP/git/etc.), then use `make -j4`(to use all 4 cores) in the RPi project folder.

The pro is you the quick compile/feedback times you're used to on your computer.
The con is this method won't work for RPi specific code (e.g. accessing GPIO, PiCamera, etc.)

Another option is to [setup cross compilation](https://forum.openframeworks.cc/t/cross-compiler-for-of-0-9-0-jessie-arm6-rpi1/21336/4), but getting everything ready is a bit laborious. (Although, once it's done, it saves time on the long run).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Yes, I think that I will look into other editors and try to compile it with the make files that you described. Will see if it can handle that at least.